# How to Extracting Autofilter list in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

How do I extract the autofilter list

I need a simple code for it

For example the array shd contain
"Sid", Apple", and so on

I dont know the procedure to extract the data frrom the list
as shown
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcbJg.png`enter code here`

Comment: Please put some efforts to write some code and explore and show what are the results and the problems. However I am submitting a code snippet which can serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Auto-filter coding is given below. It assumes you want to filter data in column B. It writes the filtered values to Sheet2.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next

     Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
     With Worksheets("Sheet1")
         .Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Sid", Operator:=XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, Criteria2:="Apple"
         LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         .Range("B1:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
      End With
   Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```